# Detecting HTTPS traffic to non-unique IP addresses

Tags: https

We're serving a website via HTTPS. Everything goes through [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), which means that our website shares IP address(es) with a whole lot of other websites.

Now, we're negotiating with some mobile providers to zero rate traffic to our site. They need a way to be able to distinguish traffic to our site from everything else. Normally we would do this by either looking at the hostname in the HTTP request or by looking at the server IP address. But the former is not available due to HTTPS and the latter is not unique to our website due to everything being proxied through CloudFlare.

Can anyone think of a way to make the distinction or some other clever way for the ISPs to near-reliably tell whether HTTPS traffic going to these IPs is going to our site?

Comment: ahh, there goes net neutrality... +1 anyway.

Comment: @Thilo, I'm _very_ much aware of that :( Unfortunately, It's not up to me to decide (yet).

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of at an ISP-only level is blocking DNS queries to this domain.

By the nature of encrypted network traffic, going to an indistinguishable IP Address it is not practically possible for the network provider to distinguish this aside from at a DNS level.

The best approach would be to send the HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP header to the mobile provider via an API and see if it is rom their network (if so then block the connection). The HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP provides the real IP Address of the user as it provides the IP that is connecting to CloudFlare.